# postgres: archive_command can't write to an nfs share

Tags: postgresql, permissions, postgresql-9.2, write-ahead-logging

I've enabled the `archive_mode` with `wal_level = hot_standby` on a master server. I intended to send the wal logs to a nfs share with:

```
archive_command = 'test ! -f /mnt/psql_wal/%f && cp -i %p /mnt/psql_wal/%f'
```

But it keeps telling me this:

```
sh: /var/lib/pgsql/archive_wal.sh: Permission denied
LOG:  archive command failed with exit code 126
DETAIL:  The failed archive command was: test ! -f /mnt/psql_wal/000000010000000000000001 && cp -i pg_xlog/000000010000000000000001 /mnt/psql_wal/000000010000000000000001
cp: failed to access ‘/mnt/psql_wal/000000010000000000000001’: Permission denied
```

Basic nfs permissions issue, you may think, but no. The following command works:

```
sudo -H -u postgres cp -i /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_xlog/000000010000000000000001 /mnt/psql_wal/000000010000000000000001
```

Is the archive command running under a different user?

Comment: Try giving complete access `777` to path `/mnt/psql_wal` to postgres user

Comment: Can you elaborate on where `/var/lib/pgsql/archive_wal.sh` does come from and whether it has anything to do with the failure immediately below?

Comment: @DanielVérité, that line was a copy/paste mistake, but the content of that script results in precisely the same commands:
`test ! -f /mnt/psql_wal/000000010000000000000001 && cp -i pg_xlog/000000010000000000000001 /mnt/psql_wal/000000010000000000000001`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably a victim of `selinux` or something like it, in which the same system OS account can have different permissions depending whether it is running as a deamon or from a command line (and, it often seems, depending on the barometric pressure, the phase of the moon, and what you had for breakfast).

You can turn it off, or put it into permissive mode where it allows the access and just logs a gripe.

Comment: Bingo! Thank you, @jjanes, that was it. After running `sudo setenforce 0` the `archive_command` worked like a charm.